How do Krishna-centric sects explain his birth in the Dvapara Yuga?
Since Krishna is Brahman according to them - how do they explain scriptures not mentioning Krishna in Yugas before the Dvapara Yuga?

There is no difference in Hari, Rama and Krishna but for different devotees different types of form were taken by the supreme

Valmiki Ramayana mentions Krishna as one of the names of Lord Rama in Yuddha Kanda.

6.105.12: bhavān nārāyaṇo devaḥ śrīmāṁś cakrāyudho vibhuḥ |
ekaśr̥ṅgo varāhas tvaṁ bhūtabhavyasapatnajit ||


6.105.13: akṣaraṁ brahmasatyaṁ ca madhye cānte ca rāghava |
lokānāṁ tvaṁ paro dharmo viṣvaksenaś caturbhujaḥ ||


6.105.14: śārṅgadhanvā hr̥ṣīkeśaḥ puruṣaḥ puruṣottamaḥ |
ajitaḥ khaḍgadhr̥g viṣṇuḥ kr̥ṣṇaś caiva br̥hadbalaḥ ||


O Rama, You are Lord Narayana, the radiant lord who holds the discus as a weapon. As the single-tusked boar, you have triumphed over your enemies in the past and will do so again in the future. You are beyond decay, the eternal Brahman. O Raghava, you represent truth from the middle to the end, the highest embodiment of dharma across the worlds. You are Vishvaksena, the one with four arms, bearing the mighty Sharnga bow. You are Hrishikesha, Purusha, and Purushottama, forever undefeated and unconquerable. You are Vishnu, the sword-wielder, and Krishna, the one with immense strength.


is this citation correct?  6 105 14 reads आतपी मण्डली मृत्युः पिङ्गलः सर्वतापनः |
कविर्विश्वो महातेजा रक्तः सर्वभवोद्भवः || ६-१०५-१४ at https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga105/yuddha_105_frame.htm @estimator

@SK My citation is from Baroda critical edition. Your citation is from Southern recension. Check 6.117.15 in your link for same sloka.

@SK Also check 6.117.28 in the link that gives second reference to Krishna (though interpreted differently in both instances).

Obviously it just means "dark-hued" in all these cases.  Not an answer. @estimator  This is like interpreting "sita' (furrow) in the Rig Veda as the Sita of the Ramayana.

@SK I wouldnt consider that obvious. Of course, I have no issue if you dont consider it as an answer.

@SK As you seem to trust western scholars more, perhaps you can check Goldman's translation for these slokas.
